# summing up in js with 2 options checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

i have this code in html

```
<input type="checkbox" value="12" id="logo" checked onchange="calculate(this);">
<input type="checkbox" value="19" id="bc" checked onchange="calculate(this);">
<input type="checkbox" value="200" id="first" onchange="calculate(this);">
<input type="checkbox" value="250" id="second" onchange="calculate(this);">

<p id="total"></p>
```

and then the js

```
var total = 0;

function calculate(option) {
    if (option.checked) {
        total += Number(option.value);
    } else {
        total -= Number(option.value);
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}
```

i need the first two `checked` checkboxes to sum up from start when page loads
and after the behavior of js to get me to 0 or to total of checkboxes when checking respectively unchecking

Comment: Use some js that runs `onload`, grabs all checkboxes that are checked, and sums their values. Also, you need to run `parseInt` on your `option.value`, because it is type string.

Comment: It doesn't work onload i already tried the elements checked are added to 0 unchecking them leads to a negative result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a class:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="12" id="logo" class='summary' checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="19" id="bc" class='summary' checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="200" id="first" class='summary'>
<input type="checkbox" value="250" id="second" class='summary'>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var summerizers = document.querySelectorAll('.summary'),
        counter = document.getElementById('counter');

    for (var i = 0, c = summerizers.length; i < c; i++) {
        summerizers[i].addEventListener('change', count);
    }

    count();

    function count() {
        var total = 0;

        for (var i = 0, c = summerizers.length; i < c; i++) {
            if (summerizers[i].checked) {
                total += parseInt(summerizers[i].value, 10);
            }
        }

        counter.value = total;
    }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r1khjrsd/

Answer (score 1):

You could add an eventlistener to the page loading and just select the options using `querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")` which selects all checkboxes, iterarate over them and sum them up.

```js
var total = 0;

function calculate(option) {
  if (option.checked) {
    total += Number(option.value);
  } else {
    total -= Number(option.value);
  }
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var options = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    const o = options[i];
    if (o.checked) total += Number(o.value);
  }
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="12" id="logo" checked onchange="calculate(this);">
<input type="checkbox" value="19" id="bc" checked onchange="calculate(this);">
<input type="checkbox" value="200" id="first" onchange="calculate(this);">
<input type="checkbox" value="250" id="second" onchange="calculate(this);">

<p id="total"></p>
```

Comment: it works man but theres a catch unchecking a value it writes to total a long value after .(dot)

Comment: Sorry I don't get your problem could you rephrase it?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use initial flag checking initial page load and checkTotal function to checked boxes on initial load

Steps:

1. Function checkedTotal to check all checked checkboxes and call calculate function with boolean value start
2. If start is true, only add checked checkbox values and restrict else part in calculate function`enter code here`

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XEyqEd?editors=1111

```js
var total = 0;

function calculate(option,start) {
    if (option.checked) {
        total += Number(option.value);
    } else {
        if(!start){
        total -= Number(option.value);
        }
    }
  
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}

function checkedTotal(){
  var checkList = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(var i =0; i < checkList.length; i++){
     calculate(checkList[i], true)
  }
}

checkedTotal()
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="12" id="logo" checked onchange="calculate(this);">
<input type="checkbox" value="19" id="bc" checked onchange="calculate(this);">
<input type="checkbox" value="200" id="first" onchange="calculate(this);">
<input type="checkbox" value="250" id="second" onchange="calculate(this);">

<p id="total"></p>
```

Comment: Im sorry this answer is not comprehensible by me there was a user post you deleted that was very clear and straight forward

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function, then recall the function `onchange` event. Don't need to pass `this` as parameter

```js
    function calculate() {
      total = 0;
      elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].checked) {
          total += Number(elements[i].value); 
        }
      }
      document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
    }
    calculate();
```

```html
  <input type="checkbox" value="12" id="logo" checked onchange="calculate();">
  <input type="checkbox" value="19" id="bc" checked onchange="calculate();">
  <input type="checkbox" value="200" id="first" onchange="calculate();">
  <input type="checkbox" value="250" id="second" onchange="calculate();">

  <p id="total"></p>
```